# cut/paste behaves like copy/paste in Excel

Tags: excel, copy-paste, paste

I, in fact two end users have seen a strange issue in Excel. 
When they CTRL+X to cut some cells and CTRL+V to paste, it does copy/paste, not cut/paste
They said it is related to the new version addin I built. I do not use or change anything about copy/cut/paste in my code at all.  I suspect it is some options in Excel, but not sure what it is. 
Do anyone know how to fix the cut/paste issue in Excel?

Edit
my addin is written in C#, Excel DNA, NetOffice, Add-In express. It is a xll addin with ribbonX and also has UDFs.  There is no VBA except during install/uninstall, I use VBA to install xll and xla.
xla returns descriptions for UDF and register help topics.

thanks

Comment: Macros running (for example in response to sheet events) can clear the clipboard. Content can still be copy/pasted if the user has the clipboard Task Pane open.

Comment: In my code, I subscribe to                 XLApp.SheetSelectionChangeEvent += ApplicationSheetSelectionChange;
                XLApp.WorkbookActivateEvent += WorkbookActivateEvent;
                XLApp.SheetActivateEvent += SheetActivatedEvent;
                XLApp.SheetCalculateEvent += ApplicationSheetCalculate;  In all events, what I do is get formula of current cell, based on it, enable/disable toolbar buttons. Will that influences cut/paste?

Comment: Thanks, Tim. The issue is not clear out, is cut/paste behaves like copy/paste. thanks

Comment: It might help to update your question with some information about your add-in.  I assumed it was in VBA but it seems it's C# ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to skype, not my code or anything. Once skype is unistalled, copy/cut/paste works fine.  see http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2003-excel/excel-2003-moving-border-when-copying-not-working/f55b0eab-13ff-489c-bd2d-d16937cd02ec?msgId=19e8fa3b-0ac2-4af0-bde7-5ac52d131f10